# Pure JS - Toggling a third class on an element accessed via getElementByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, function, class, toggle

I have a div element with 2 classes that I would like to toggle a third class on depending on whether another element is active.

The other element's 'active' class is working, but I cannot work out how to toggle 'class3' on an element - I am getting the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined

but I am unsure exactly what about this function is incorrect. I'm still learning so this may be obvious!

HTML:

```
<div class="class1 class2"></div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", 
myFunction); 

function myFunction(){

if (document.getElementById("otherElement").classList.contains("active")){
 document.getElementsByClassName("class2").classList.toggle("class3");
}}
```

I also want to do this in pure JS, even if jQuery may be easier just to learn from the ground up

Comment: The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) are your friend. You should read them. `getElementsByClassName` does not return an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName("class2")` returns an array. You'll need to loop through each index of it.

```js
if (document.getElementById("otherElement").classList.contains("active")){
  const size = document.getElementsByClassName("post-text").length;
  
  if (size > 0) {
   for (let i = 0; i < size; i++){
      document.getElementsByClassName("post-text")[i].classList.toggle("class3");
   }
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! I hadn't even considered I wold need to loop through it

Answer (score 0):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) return an HTMLCollection, an array even if there's only one element with that class, add `[0]` to select the first one and `toggle`  the `class3`

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", 
myFunction); 

function myFunction(){

if (document.getElementById("otherElement").classList.contains("active")){
 document.getElementsByClassName("class2")[0].classList.toggle("class3");
}}
```

```css
.class1{
  background: red;
}

.class2{
  background: blue;
}

.class3{
  background: green;
}

div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1 class2">hello</div>
<div id="otherElement" class="active">
there
</div>
<button id="button">
click
</button>
```